# Enviar archivo adjunto por PHP, pero con formato HTML

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando una aplicación donde el siguiente código es la parte de contactarnos, en donde el usuario agrega su nombre, email, selecciona un cargo, teléfono y mensaje. Acabo de agregar un campo de adjuntar archivo, **pero quisiera saber cual es el error dentro del código**, puesto que solo recibo los datos del usuario, pero no recibo ningún archivo a mi correo. las pruebas las realizo desde un servidor

Aquí dejo el código PHP.

```
<?php

//Variables para los campos de texto
$nombre = strip_tags($_POST["nombre"]);
$email = strip_tags($_POST["email"]);
$cargo = strip_tags($_POST["cargo"]);
$telefono = strip_tags($_POST["telefono"]);
$mensaje = strip_tags($_POST["mensaje"]);

//Variables para los datos del archivo
$nameFile = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$sizeFile = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$typeFile = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$tempFile = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

$content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'])));

$fecha = time();
$fechaFormato = date('d/m/y', $fecha);

$corredoDestino = 'prueba@gmail.com';

$eol = "\r\n";
//asunto del correo
$titulo = "Mensaje de la web recibido";

// -> mensaje en formato Multipart MIME
$cabecera = "MIME-VERSION: 1.0" .$eol;
$cabecera .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" .$fecha. "\"" .$eol;
$cabecera .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" .$eol;
$cabecera .= "From: {$mail}";

//Primera parte del cuerpo del mensaje
$cuerpo = "--=C=T=E=C=" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= $eol; //línea vacía
$cuerpo .= "Haz recibido un mensaje atravez de la página solmit.net" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "Mensaje enviado por: " .$nombre. "" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "ponerse en contacto con: " .$email. "" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "Selecciono el cargo de: " .$cargo. "" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "El teléfono de la persona es: " .$telefono. "" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "Mensaje: " .$mensaje. "" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= $eol;
$cuerpo .= " Enviado el: " .$fechaFormato. "" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= $eol;

// -> Segunda parte del mensaje (archivo adjunto)
    // -> encabezado de la parte
$cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" .$nameFile. "\"" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= "filename= " .$nameFile. "" .$eol;
$cuerpo .= $eol; //línea vacía

// $fp = fopen($tempFile, "rb");
// $file = fread($fp, $sizeFile);
// $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

// $cuerpo .= $file .$eol;
// $cuerpo .= $eol; //linea vacia
// //Delimitador de final del mensaje.
// $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=--" .$eol;

//Enviar el correo
$envio = mail($corredoDestino, $titulo, $cuerpo, $cabecera);

if($envio) {
    header('Location: index.html');
} else {
    echo "Error de envío";
}
```

?>

Este es el HTML la parte del Form.

```
<form method="post" action="enviar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="NOMBRE" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="correo" placeholder="CORREO" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <select class="form-control" name="cargo" required>
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccionar Cargo</option>
                                        <option value="Programador Web C#.Net">Programador Web C#.Net</option>
                                        <option value="Programador Senior Web en C#.Net Bilingue">Programador Senior Web en C#.Net Bilingue</option>
                                      </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <input type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control" id="telefono" placeholder="TELÉFONO" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="mensaje" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje" required></textarea>
                                </div>

                                <div class="label-form" style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px;">
                                    <p class="p">Adjuntar CV:</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="style-archivo">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
                                    <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo" placeholder="" size="30" />
                                </div>

                                <button class="btn-primary-f" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                                <p class="p">+ Información llámenos:</br> <span>0505050505</span></p>
```

Comment: Hola Dominic, te recomiendo que leas [ask] y que luego edites tu pregunta para añadir más información: qué hace el código que compartes, qué resultado esperas al ejecutarlo, qué resultado obtienes. Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad, y las preguntas sin un enunciado claro son más difíciles de contestar y no de gran utilidad para la comunidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo es la primera vez que realizo una pregunta por esta comunidad.

Comment: Sin problemas, todos empezamos en algún momento. A ver si hay suerte y te podemos ayudar :-)

Comment: Si hablamos de ayuda, es ahora o nunca :D

Comment: ¿Entonces lo que quieres es poder enviar archivos adjuntos en tu email?

Comment: Claro que si, pero estoy buscando la forma como enviarlo por php.

Answer (score 0):

En la [respuesta de Simon Mokhele en Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428803/3695983), puedes encontrar un ejemplo de cómo se puede añadir un archivo como adjunto a un email con `mail`. Este es su código:

```
$file = $path.$filename;
$content = file_get_contents( $file);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);

// header
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

// message & attachment
$nmessage = "--".$uid."\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$nmessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$nmessage .= "--".$uid."--";

if (mail($mailto, $subject, $nmessage, $header)) {
    return true; // Or do something here
} else {
  return false;
}
```

---

Ahora podemos adaptarlo a tu caso particular:

> **PRECAUCIÓN**: No he podido probar este código en un servidor por lo que no puedo asegurar 100% que funciona. Escribiendo por pantalla los valores, parece que no debería haber problema, pero cuando lo he subido a un servidor me ha dado fallo (no relacionado con el código, pero con la propia configuración del servidor).
>
> **ADEMÁS**: **el código original que compartes puede sufrir ataques de XSS** al no procesar las entradas de usuario correctamente. NO he corregido esos errores, pero te recomiendo que leas sobre XSS y cómo evitarlo en PHP.

```
<?php
    $nombre = isset( $_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $cargo = isset($_POST['cargo']) ? $_POST['cargo'] : '';
    $telefono = isset($_POST['telefono']) ? $_POST['telefono'] : '';
    $mensajeusuario = isset($_POST['mensaje']) ? $_POST['mensaje'] : '';

    $fichero = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $contenidofichero = file_get_contents( $fichero );
    $contenidoficheor = chunk_split(base64_encode($contenidofichero));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $nombrefichero = basename($fichero);

    $fecha = time();
    $fechaFormato = date('d/m/y h:i:s', $fecha);

    //Cpmtemtodp del mensaje
    $titulo = "Mensaje de la web recibido";
    $contenido = '
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <title>' .$titulo. '</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <h2>Haz recibido un mensaje atravez de la página</h2>
                            <p>Mensaje enviado por: <strong>' .$nombre. '</strong></p>
                            <p>ponerse en contacto con: <strong>' .$email. ',</strong></p>
                            <p>Selecciono el cargo de: <strong>' .$cargo. ',</strong></p>
                            <p>El teléfono de la persona es: <strong>' .$telefono. ',</strong></p>
                            <p>Mensaje: '.$mensajeusuario.'</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p>Enviado el: <strong>' .$fechaFormato. '</strong></p>
                        </body>
                    </html>';

    //Configuración de los encabezados
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n";

    // primero ponemos el mensaje y luego el archivo adjunto, cerrando con el serparador
    $mensaje = "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $mensaje .= $contenido."\r\n\r\n";

    $mensaje = "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$nombrefichero."\"\r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $mensaje .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename=\"".$nombrefichero."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $mensaje .= $contenidofichero."\r\n\r\n";
    $mensaje .= "--".$uid."--";

    $para = 'alvaromontoro@gmail.com';
    $envio = mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $headers);

    if($envio) {
        $miresultado = '<h4>El correo ha sido enviado! Gracias por ponerse en contacto con nosotros.</h4>';
    } else {
        $miresultado = '<h4>No se envio el correo.</h4>';
    }

    //header('Location: index.html');
    echo $miresultado;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

gracias por el aporte estuve probando desde un servidor, y tienes razon no procesa correctamente al usuario estuve investigando mas y me encontre con este código con type= text/plain. Este fragmento de código lo estuve probando y resulta que si envia el archivo todo correcto pero ya no me envía el cuerpo del mensaje, mejor dicho la información del usuario. Quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal en esta parte del código

```
<?php

    //Variables para los campos de texto
    $nombre = strip_tags($_POST["nombre"]);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST["email"]);
    $cargo = strip_tags($_POST["cargo"]);
    $telefono = strip_tags($_POST["telefono"]);
    $mensaje = strip_tags($_POST["mensaje"]);

    //Variables para los datos del archivo
    $nameFile = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $sizeFile = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $typeFile = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tempFile = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

    $fecha = time();
    $fechaFormato = date('d/m/y', $fecha);

    $corredoDestino = 'prueba@gmail.com';

    //asunto del correo
    $titulo = "Mensaje de la web recibido";

    // -> mensaje en formato Multipart MIME
    $cabecera = "MIME-VERSION: 1.0\r\n";
    $cabecera .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;";
    $cabecera .= "boundary=\"=C=T=E=C=\"\r\n";
    $cabecera .= "From: {$mail}";

    //Primera parte del cuerpo del mensaje
    $cuerpo = "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-type: text/plain";
    $cuerpo .= "charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; //línea vacía
    $cuerpo .= "Haz recibido un mensaje atravez de la página solmit.net \r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Mensaje enviado por: " .$nombre. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "ponerse en contacto con: " .$email. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Selecciono el cargo de: " .$cargo. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "El teléfono de la persona es: " .$telefono. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Mensaje: " .$mensaje. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= " Enviado el: " .$fechaFormato. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";

    // -> Segunda parte del mensaje (archivo adjunto)
        // -> encabezado de la parte
    $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ";
    $cuerpo .= "name=" .$nameFile. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
    $cuerpo .= "filename= " .$nameFile. "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; //línea vacía

    $fp = fopen($tempFile, "rb");
    $file = fread($fp, $sizeFile);
    $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

    $cuerpo .= "$file\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n"; //linea vacia
    //Delimitador de final del mensaje.
    $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=--\r\n";

    //Enviar el correo
    $envio = mail($corredoDestino, $titulo, $cuerpo, $cabecera);

    if($envio) {
        header('Location: index.html');
    } else {
        echo "Error de envío";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, debes crear una nueva publicación en lugar de responder tu pregunta con una nueva pregunta. Limita tus respuestas a respuestas. Te recomiendo que leas [answer] y [ask] en el centro de ayuda para más información.

Comment: Esta bien, entonces realizare otra pregunta, muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Intenta añadir toda la información pertinente en la nueva pregunta: valores de las variables (las puedes conseguir con var_dump o print_r), logs (si puedes), configuración (valores del php.ini)... y si no obtienes respuesta, mándame un mensaje y le echo un vistazo, quizás pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Una pregunta poco ignorante pero, ¿se puede enviar mensaje por stackoverflow?.

Comment: No, no se puede mandar un mensaje a un usuario en particular. Puedes entrar al [chat] y poner un nombre con una arroba (p.e. @AlvaroMontoro) y le aparecerá una notificación al usuario. O si quieres mandarme un mensaje, comenta en esta pregunta y lo veo

Comment: Alvaro Montoro acabo de modificar mi pregunta, en el que el código PHP fue modificado y lo que me comentabas sobre el tema de la inseguridad XSS, sobre que el usuario envía sus datos y no llegaba sus datos completos. el nuevo código que modifique tal vez pueda ser que sea permito y no sea detectado como XSS.